# Parsing more than 1 xml file within an svn transaction commit using pysvn

Tags: python, xml, parsing, svn, pysvn

As I'm still not an expert in python, I want to cat each changed xml file within a transaction within a commit to an svn repository and do something. In this case I check if an xml-file exists an then send out an email. For this I use pysvn and lxml to parse for the corresponding tag. This works but just for only one file. If I have 2 files with the tag I dows not work. Furthermore it makes sense, if there are more than 1 xml file which has the tag "Needs Review" to send out just 1 email with a list of the corresponding files. Does anybody have an idea how to change the "for changedFile..." to realize this?

```
#!/bin/env python
import os
import sys
import subprocess 
# Import pysvn libs to act with svn
import pysvn
# Import smtplib for the actual sending function
import smtplib
# Import the email modules we'll need
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
# Use lxml lib to parse tree for status
from lxml import html

#tmpFile = open('D:\my.log', 'w')

repository = sys.argv[1]
transactionId = sys.argv[2]
transaction = pysvn.Transaction(repository, transactionId, is_revision=True)

for changedFile in transaction.changed():
    tree = html.fromstring(transaction.cat(changedFile))
    if tree.xpath('//topic/@status')[0] == "Needs Review":
        #tmpFile.writelines("This topic needs review")

        # me == my email address
        # you == recipient's email address
        me = "test@example.com"
        you = "test2@example.com"

        # Create message container - the correct MIME type is multipart/alternative.
        msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
        msg['Subject'] = "TODO Review JiveX Doku"
        msg['From'] = me
        msg['To'] = you

        # Create the body of the message (a plain-text and an HTML version).
        text = "Some Text and please check this File."
        html = """\
        <html>
            <head></head>
            <body>
            <p>The following commited Files need a Review.
            Please Check.<br>
            Here is the List of Files with links: <a href=".../file1">file 1</a><br><a href=".../file2">file 2</a>.
            </p>
            </body>
        </html>
        """

        # Record the MIME types of both parts - text/plain and text/html.
        part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
        part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')

        # Attach parts into message container.
        # According to RFC 2046, the last part of a multipart message, in this case
        # the HTML message, is best and preferred.
        msg.attach(part1)
        msg.attach(part2)

        # Send the message via local SMTP server.
        s = smtplib.SMTP('192.168.1.20')
        # sendmail function takes 3 arguments: sender's address, recipient's address
        # and message to send - here it is sent as one string.
        s.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string())
        s.quit()
```